# .Net core - Is it possible to implement Custom claim validation with dynamic claim based on incoming request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware, claims

Is it possible to implement custom ClaimsValidation in .net core 3.1 or .net 6? If yes, how?

We have common single rest endpoint to return any of our reports based on the 'reportname' mentioned in the request payload. Now the claim validation is kind of hard coded to "AllReportAccess" but need to fine grain it for better control

Existing Implementation:

```
[ClaimsValidation(Claims.AllReportAccess)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetReport(){}
```

**where ClaimsValidation is custom ActionFilterAttribute

Expected Implementation:

Since the report name in the request payload can vary from request to request our claim validation also needs to be changed accordingly to the requested report.

Claims.AllReportAccess can't be harcoded, but claim validation should be dynamic if the incoming request comes for Report2 then we need check for higher order claim like Claims.AllReportAccess or **specific report access** like Claims.Report**2** access but not only Claims.AllReportAccess claim validation always.

we need to keep "Claims.AllReportAccess" to support backward compatibility.

If the above requirement can't be achieved via in-built or custom ClaimsValidation attribute, is **Authorization filters** or custom middleware, way to go?

Comment: I would have a look at the [AuthorizationPolicy][1] logic for this. 

  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @Qpirate, appreciate you efforts. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0 is the exact one I'm looking for..

Answer (score 0):

We have something similar and due to the fact, that the validation has to be made against some dynamic value of the incoming request (route, query or body parameter) we wrote a helper service that will be called within the controller method and validates the dynamic parameter values after extracting via model binding:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(IncomingRequest request)
{
    permissionApprovalService.ThrowIfNotHasEffectivePermissions(request.SomeParameter, User, Claims.SomeSpecificClaim);
}
```

Additionally we have a middleware registered that catches the specific type of exception thrown by this service and returns a 403 error including an error message.

Due to the fact that you have to make your validation against a dynamic value within the incoming request it is much harder work to implement such a logic somewhere globally instead of providing a helper method within the controller method after model binding. The only burden by this approach is that you have to ensure that this method will correctly called, but that could be ensured by corresponding unit tests for each controller method.